# local.properties unused property for custom variables

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I am setting some local variables for build type signing configs, and it seems to be working. However Intellij (Android Studio) seems to think these variables in my `local.properties` file are unused.

Is this just one of those "turn off the linter" problems, or is there actually a way to solve this and tell the linter to do it's job correctly?

Example of usage:

local.properties:

```
storeFile=/home/user/dir/file # <-- says it's unused
storePass=pass1234 # <-- unused
# ...
```

build.gradle

```
android {
  Properties properties = new Properties()
  properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())

  signingConfigs {
    'release (signed)' {
      storeFile file(properties.getProperty('storeFile'))
      storePassword properties.getProperty('storePass')
      keyAlias properties.getProperty('keyAlias')
      keyPassword properties.getProperty('keyPass')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please file an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce the case to it. Thank you